# ElasticSearch Failed to parse mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to create new index with put request http://localhost:9200/songs
with following mapping

```
{
"mappings": {
    "songs": {
        "properties": {
            "artist_name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "songs": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lyric": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [songs : {properties={artist_name={type=text}, songs={type=nested, properties={lyric={type=keyword}, name={type=keyword}}}}}]"
```

The json structure is valid. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using ES version 7 where the `type` has been deprecated as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html):

Change your mapping to the below and it should work.

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "artist_name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "songs": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "lyric": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!